# How can I check more than one column with columntocheck command?

Tags: javascript

I want to save the date of operation and I found that code:

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

var COLUMNTOCHECK = 9 ;
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
var SHEETNAME = 'Grupy Fb'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

However I want to run it on different columns, what should I do?

Comment: What library you are using?

Comment: What is columntocheck? This is supposed to be code for Google Sheets or what? You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly but if you want more than just one column to set the date for just make an Array out of COLUMNTOCHECK with the columns you want and iterate over it.